# translation of display name by current context

Tags: c#, model, localization, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create translations for display name (either `DisplayAttribute` or `DisplayNameAttribute`) based on current request context. Custom attribute can't be placed in any web project (Model is separated) and is used also for Enums. Localization process isn't simple, can't use resources (even translation is based on both user and dictionary key).

Is there any way to achieve this using Model binding, or any other?

Comment: No, since you can only assign constants to attribute properties.

Comment: Ok. I used NInject Factory pattern.